# Not showing data fetched from API in browser but showing in console

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I fetched data from a quotes API but it is showing quote but it is not author name.

HTML CODE :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Random Quote Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="quote">
    
            <p id="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Earum, sint.</p>

            <span id="author"></span>
            
        </div>
    
        <button id="btn">Next Quote</button>
    
    </div>
</body>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

JavaScript Code :

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container")
const quote = document.querySelector(".quote")
const desc = document.querySelector("#content")
const btn = document.querySelector("#btn")
const author = document.querySelector("#author")

btn.onclick = () => {
    
    const fetchData = async() => {
        
        const url = `https://api.quotable.io/quotes/random`
        const response = await fetch(url)
        const data = await response.json()
        const x = data[0]
    
        const quoteData = x.content
        const authorName = x.author
        quote.innerText = quoteData
        author.innerText = authorName
    }
    fetchData()
}
```

I was trying to fetch data from a quote API and trying to show the data in the browser
but it is not showing authorName in browser but showing correctly in console.

Comment: Because by setting `quote.innerText = ...` you are replacing the content of your `<div class="quote">` and the `<span id="author">` which is originally within this div is not part of the DOM anymore ... You probably want to do `desc.innerText = ...` instead

Comment: quote is parent div, if you set innertext on that it will replace the inside content(which has you auther element).

Answer (score 0):

The thing your code is doing is replacing innerText of `<div class="quote">`. It replaces `<p id="content">` and `<span id="author">` with a quote. That’s why you can see only the content and not an author.
To fix it you should change innerText of `<p id="content">`, not `<div class="quote">`

```
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const quote = document.querySelector(".quote");
const desc = document.querySelector("#content");
const btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
const author = document.querySelector("#author");

btn.onclick = () => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const url = `https://api.quotable.io/quotes/random`;
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        const x = data[0];

        const quoteData = x.content;
        const authorName = x.author;
        desc.innerText = quoteData; // Changed
        author.innerText = authorName;
    };
    fetchData();
};
```